# How do I reverse the order of columns in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, transpose, array-formulas, google-sheets-query, textjoin

before

```
Column 1   Column 2   Column 3   Column 4   Column 5   
data        data       data       data        data
data        data       data       data        data
data                   data       data        data
data                   data                   data
```

after

```
Column 5   Column 4   Column 3   Column 2   Column 1   
data        data       data       data        data
data        data       data       data        data
data        data       data                   data
data                   data                   data
```

It's got to be simple but I can't find it!

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({A:E}, "select "&
 TEXTJOIN(",", 1, "Col"&SORT(TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(A:E)), 1, 0)), 0))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thanks - got this error - Error
Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: PARSE_ERROR: Encountered " <ID> "selectCol5 "" at line 1, column 1. Was expecting one of: <EOF> "select" ... "where" ... "group" ... "pivot" ... "order" ... "skipping" ... "limit" ... "offset" ... "label" ... "format" ... "options" ...

Comment: Range is A:1 - CR30

Comment: error says you removed that space: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BE5zf.png